# When $G$ is compact, every $G$-space is proper

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, compactness, topological-groups

A $G$-space is (generally) a topological space $X$ equipped with a continuous action by a topological group $G$.

A $G$-space $X$ is called **proper** if the map $\theta:G\times X\rightarrow X\times X, ~(g,x)\mapsto (x,g\cdot x)$ is proper in the sense that the inverse images of compact sets are compact sets.

Suppose $G$ is a compact group, how to show that every $G$-space $X$ is proper?

Comment: We need that $X$ is Hausdorff. The proof in the accepted answer also uses this. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need that $X$ is Hausdorff. Let $C$ be a compact subset of $X\times X$, and $p_1:X\times X\rightarrow X$ the projection on the first factor. $p(C)=D$ is compact. $\theta^{-1}(C)$ is contained in $G\times D$ which is compact as product of compact sets. Since $C$ is closed, $\theta^{-1}(C)$ is closed, and we deduce that it is compact.

Comment: I know that $\theta^{-1}(C)$ is contained in $G\times X$,but why it is contained in $G\times D$?

Comment: If $(g,x) \in \theta^{-1}(C)$, then $(x,gx) = \theta(g,x) \in C$, so $x \in D$ by the definition of $D$. But then $(g,x) \in G \times D$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg 1) Why don't we use the explicit formula of the action? It means it could have been anything as long it is continuous. 2) Does it matter if  we use  $p_1$ or $p_2$  ?

Comment: 1) There is no explicit formula for the action, the action is arbitrary. 2) Try to find out. Working this out will help you to really understand the present proof.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Ok, Why do you say it is arbitrary? Isn't  $(g,x) \mapsto (x, g.x)$a explicit formula? Given by  multiplication on one entry and nothing on the other, instead  of any other function. But I see now that you use it to prove the inclusion, so I guess that's when we need it to be defined like that